# Executing a Query in a odata controller results in a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've created a repository to call a sql query from within an aspnet core boilerplate project, when I call the query from with in a odata controller it results in the following error:

"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

my query repository is defined as follows:

public class CommonRepository : MyRepositoryBase, ICommonRepository
    {
        private readonly IActiveTransactionProvider _transactionProvider;

```
    public CommonRepository(IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> dbContextProvider, IActiveTransactionProvider transactionProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
        _transactionProvider = transactionProvider;
    }

    public async void MyQuery()
    {
        try
        {
            EnsureConnectionOpen();

            using (var command = CreateCommand("select *  from sometable", CommandType.Text))
            {
                await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    private DbCommand CreateCommand(string commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var command = Context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.CommandType = commandType;
        command.Transaction = GetActiveTransaction();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        return command;
    }

    private void EnsureConnectionOpen()
    {
        var connection = Context.Database.GetDbConnection();

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }

    private DbTransaction GetActiveTransaction()
    {
        return (DbTransaction)_transactionProvider.GetActiveTransaction(new ActiveTransactionProviderArgs
        {
            {"ContextType", typeof(MyDbContext) },
            {"MultiTenancySide", MultiTenancySide }
        });
    }

}
```

}

I try to make a call to MyQuery in the following odata controller:

```
[DontWrapResult]
[AbpMvcAuthorize]
public class MyReportsController : AbpODataEntityController<MyReport>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly ICommonRepository _commonRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

    public MyReportsController(IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager, IRepository<MyReport> repository, ICommonRepository commonRepository)
        : base(repository)
    {
        _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
        _commonRepository = commonRepository;
    }

    public override IQueryable<MyReport> Get()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        {
            _commonRepository.MyQuery();
            unitOfWork.Complete();
        }
        return base.Get();
    }

}
```

which results in the "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." error.

I've tried to wrap the Query call in its own unit of work, but I still get the same issue. Can anyone offer any advice to resolve please.

Comment: `Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)`

Comment: Thanks, adding MultipleActiveResultSets=true to the connection string seemed to resolve the need for having a new unit of work for this.

Comment: Post that as an answer.